# Woocommerce shipping cost based on item quantity for specific shipping class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, product-quantity

I posted this code a few hours ago. I managed to get through one of the issues, but i have only one question now. This code works well but I need to multiply the cost for every single item using an specific shipping class and then add it to the regular shipping cost.

Example if I have 5 products in the cart:

- 2 of them use shipping-class-1 ($70 extra shipping cost for product)
- 3 of them use shipping-class-2 ($50 extra shipping cost for product)

So if (for example) the regular shipping costs $120 then the shipping should be **($120 + $290) = $410**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ph_add_extra_cost_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2);
if( ! function_exists('ph_add_extra_cost_based_on_shipping_class') ) {
    function ph_add_extra_cost_based_on_shipping_class( $shipping_rates, $package ){

        $handling_fee_based_on_shipping_class = array(
            array(
                'shipping_classes'  =>  array( 'shipping-class-1'),         // Shipping Class slug array
                'adjustment'        => 70,                                  // Adjustment
            ),
            array(
                'shipping_classes'  =>  array( 'shipping-class-2' ),
                'adjustment'        =>  50,
            ),
        );

        $shipping_method_ids = array( 'cologistics-shipping' );     // Shipping methods on which adjustment has to be applied

        $adjustment = null;
        foreach( $package['contents'] as  $line_item ) {
            $line_item_shipping_class = $line_item['data']->get_shipping_class();
            if( ! empty($line_item_shipping_class) ) {
                foreach( $handling_fee_based_on_shipping_class as $adjustment_data ) {
                    if( in_array( $line_item_shipping_class, $adjustment_data['shipping_classes']) ) {
                        $adjustment = ( $adjustment_data['adjustment'] > $adjustment ) ? $adjustment_data['adjustment'] : $adjustment;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if( ! empty($adjustment) ) {
            foreach( $shipping_rates as $shipping_rate ) {
                $shipping_method_id = $shipping_rate->get_method_id();
                if( in_array($shipping_method_id, $shipping_method_ids) ) {
                    $shipping_rate->set_cost( (float) $shipping_rate->get_cost() + $adjustment );
                }
            }
        }

        return $shipping_rates;
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't require any code normally… You should set your shipping method as follow *(so first remove your code and save)*:

[image]

1) So you will keep **`120`** as global cost in your shipping method.

2) Then for each related desired shipping class you will add in the corresponding field:

- **`[qty]*70`** for `shipping-class-1`
- **`[qty]*50`** for `shipping-class-2`
- **Calculation type:** `Per class: Charge shipping for each shipping class individually`

This will work and will add to the cost an amount by chipping class based on cart item quantity.

---

For a custom shipping method based on your code, you should use the following to handle item quantity:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ph_add_extra_cost_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2);
if( ! function_exists('ph_add_extra_cost_based_on_shipping_class') ) {
    function ph_add_extra_cost_based_on_shipping_class( $shipping_rates, $package ){

        $handling_fee_based_on_shipping_class = array(
            array(
                'shipping_classes'  =>  array( 'shipping-class-1'),         // Shipping Class slug array
                'adjustment'        => 70,                                  // Adjustment
            ),
            array(
                'shipping_classes'  =>  array( 'shipping-class-2' ),
                'adjustment'        =>  50,
            ),
        );

        $shipping_method_ids = array( 'cologistics-shipping' );     // Shipping methods on which adjustment has to be applied

        $adjustment = 0;

        foreach( $package['contents'] as  $line_item ) {
            $line_item_shipping_class = $line_item['data']->get_shipping_class();
            if( ! empty($line_item_shipping_class) ) {
                foreach( $handling_fee_based_on_shipping_class as $adjustment_data ) {
                    if( in_array( $line_item_shipping_class, $adjustment_data['shipping_classes']) ) {
                        $adjustment += $adjustment_data['adjustment'] * $line_item['quantity'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if( $adjustment > 0 ) {
            foreach( $shipping_rates as $shipping_rate ) {
                $shipping_method_id = $shipping_rate->get_method_id();
                if( in_array($shipping_method_id, $shipping_method_ids) ) {
                    $shipping_rate->set_cost( (float) $shipping_rate->get_cost() + $adjustment );
                }
            }
        }

        return $shipping_rates;
    }
}
```

It should work handling car item quantity additional cost…

> Don't forget to refresh shipping methods going to shipping settings, then disable/save and re-enable/save any shipping method in the related shipping zone.

Other [answer threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A3730754%20woocommerce_package_rates) related to `woocommerce_package_rates` hook.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec! Thanks for you fast response as always. I tried your code, but nothing happens :(

Comment: @LoikTheAztec, indeed i cannot use the flat rate option because I am using a custom shipping method created specifically for a local shipping service called Cologistics. It is a plugin developed by a custom programmer, which retrieves the cost of the shipping with the help of an external api. That is why i found the first code. As i said it works, but i need to multiply it for every item in the cart. I thought it was easier :( Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Voltaki I have re-updated my answer adding back some different code, based on yours…

Comment: @LoikTheAztec Yes! It worked! You are the best. Thank you so much.

Comment: @LoikTheAztec Hello, I am here again. It did work as I said before, but it is not working with instances of the shipping method. I need to adjust the price for only one specific instance. I tried with the woocommerce classic flate rate and it didnt work also. For example if i set:  $shipping_method_ids = array( 'flat_rate' ); it adjusts the price for all flat rate instances configured, but when I change that to: 'flat_rate:5' it stops working and it returns to the original cost.

Comment: IN that case you need to replace: `$shipping_method_id = $shipping_rate->get_method_id();` by `$shipping_method_id = $shipping_rate->get_id();` to handle the complete shipping method rate ID as for example `flat_rate:5` … see: [Woocommerce apidocs class WC_Shipping_Rate available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html)

Comment: I'm testing with flat_rate ids. Replacing that line didn't work. :(

Comment: @Voltaki Something else doesn't work in your case as I have tested it a lot of times before in different answers and it works…

Comment: I am sorry. It worked with flat_rate indeed but not before refreshing and changing many times the shipping method options and the cart items. But, although it worked with flat_rate I cannot make it work with my custom shipping method. Do you have any clues?